# Can I run the command in specific terminal?

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, virtualenv

OS: Linux mint 19.2 Cinnamon
SHELL: Zsh
TERMINAL: Tilix

I want to create a shell script. which have 2 steps.

1. Open the new terminal.
2. Run `source bin/activate` at terminal that I opened.

How do I run `source bin/activate` command in specific shell?

I think keypoint is pid.

I think that If I use pid, it works.

**How do I run `source bin/activate` command in specific shell?**

Relationship:[I want to create the launcher. When I click it, which open the shell and run `source ~/venv/bin/activate && cd ~/workspace/python_script`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563838/i-want-to-create-the-launcher-when-i-click-it-which-open-the-shell-and-run-so)

Comment: Why not just put it in the shell init file?

Comment: What is a init file? .zshrc?

Comment: You've asked the same question twice.

Comment: @pastelkona Yes.

Comment: Yes but, I just ask that can i run source bin/activate command in specific shell.

Comment: @NasirRiley But in your way, when I open the shell, it always run source bin/activate. I want to separate icon of "open terminal" and "open terminal and run source bin/activate".

Answer (score 0):

We will use the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable to source a custom startup file. Create a directory, e.g. `~/.config/zsh/` and create a `.zshrc` file in there with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# By default, this file will not be sourced by zsh.

# Source config files at the default places:
. ~/.zshrc
. ~/.zshenv

# custom commands:
. ~/bin/activate
```

Now you can run (replace `$TERMINAL` with your terminal emulator, e.g `tilix`)

```
ZDOTDIR=~/.config/zsh $TERMINAL -e zsh
```

to open a new terminal running zsh with a custom `ZDOTDIR`.

Also See: [Zsh Startup/Shutdown files – ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zsh#Startup/Shutdown_files)